# AngularJS scope data not displaying on partial html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-promise

I am facing one weird scenario while using angularJS. [new to AngularJS]

I am calling one function from my index.html which is defined in controller.js.

```
<li><a  ng-click="casualShirts()" data-ng-controller="MyCtrl2" href="#/view2">Casual Shirts</a></li>
```

/#View2 is my partial2.html.

In Controller the code is:

```
            app.controller('MyCtrl2', ['$scope', '$location', 'UserFactory', '$q', function ($scope, $location, UserFactory, $q) {

            //$scope.home = UserFactory.home.query();

            $scope.casualShirts = function () {
                console.log("casualshirts");
                $scope.home = UserFactory.casualshirts.query({key: 'Casual Shirts'}, function (home) {
                    console.log('(callback) read more ' + $scope.home.length); // <= will log correct length
                });

                console.log('read more ' + $scope.home.length); // <= will always log 0
                $scope.$watch('home.length', function (length) {
                    if (length) { // <= first time length is changed from undefined to 0
                        console.log('(watch) read more ' + $scope.home.length); // <= will log correct length
                    }
                });

                console.log("casualshirts length - " + $scope.home.length);

                var deferred = $q.defer();

                var promise = deferred.promise;
                promise.then(function (result) {
                    alert('success - ' + result);
                }, function (reason) {

                      alert('Error - ' + reason);
                });

                $location.path('/view2');
            }

        }]);
```

The data is returned properly from service and I can see them in console.log when watch is applied. logs are:

```
casualshirts controllers.js:29
read more 0 controllers.js:34
casualshirts length - 0 controllers.js:41
(callback) read more 527 controllers.js:31
(watch) read more 527
```

But the same data is not coming to UI and its not visible.

Weird part is: If same

```
$scope.home = UserFactory.home.query();
```

Services.js - EDIT

```
            var services = angular.module('ngdemo.services', ['ngResource']);


            services.factory('UserFactory', ['$resource', '$rootScope', function ($resource, $rootScope) {
                /*alert("I am here service");*/
                console.log("casualshirts service");
                return  {


                    casualshirts: $resource('/rest/users/:key', {}, {
                        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true , params: {key : '@key'} },
                        create: {method: 'POST'}
                    }),
                    allresults: $resource('/rest/users/cats', {}, {
                        query: {method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
                        // create: {method: 'POST'}
                    })};
            }]);
```

is called without being inside any $scope.casualShirts function, data is coming to UI.

Am I missing anything here? Please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share the source of UserFactory in order to give better support? If it is promise based then the assignment wouldn't get the result but a promise.

Comment: I used promise only to check why data is not coming. editing my post with service of User factory

Comment: @HeberLZ - I edited with Userfactory code.